# Embedding Python3 in Qt 5

Tags: python, c++, qt, qmake, qt-signals

I would like to embed Python interpreter 3.4 into a Qt 5.2.1 application (64-bit).
However I'm having build issues, I mean when I include Python header in the main.cpp it compiles fine.

```
#include <python.h>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();

  return a.exec();
}
```

but when I put it anywhere else (after Qt headers)

```
//
// embedpytest.cpp
//
#include <QLibrary>
#include <python.h>


EmbedPyTest::EmbedPyTest()
{
}
```

I get compile errors:

```
C:\Python34\include\object.h:435: error: C2059: syntax error : ';'
C:\Python34\include\object.h:435: error: C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

[image]

It's very similar problem to this one, but the solution is not working

[Embedding Python in Qt 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078060/embedding-python-in-qt-5)

Anyone knows how to solve this issue ? or suggest some clean workaround so that python.h and Qt5
can live together happily ever after ?

Comment: How did that answer not work for you?  Because it worked for me with exactly the same Python and Qt version as you.

Comment: seems impossible. I'm using 64-bit python 3.4, 64-bit Qt 5.2.1, and visual studio 2012

Comment: I was using g++, perhaps that was the difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The offending line is this:

```
PyType_Slot *slots; /* terminated by slot==0. */
```

The problem is that with this line, "slots" is a keyword by default in Qt. In order to use that variable name in other projects, you will need to use this in your project file:

```
CONFIG += no_keywords
```

For details, see the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#using-qt-with-3rd-party-signals-and-slots):

> Using Qt with 3rd Party Signals and Slots
>
> It is possible to use Qt with a 3rd party signal/slot mechanism. You can even use both mechanisms in the same project. Just add the following line to your qmake project (.pro) file.

```
CONFIG += no_keywords
```

> It tells Qt not to define the moc keywords signals, slots, and emit, because these names will be used by a 3rd party library, e.g. Boost. Then to continue using Qt signals and slots with the no_keywords flag, simply replace all uses of the Qt moc keywords in your sources with the corresponding Qt macros Q_SIGNALS (or Q_SIGNAL), Q_SLOTS (or Q_SLOT), and Q_EMIT.

Comment: makes sense but doesn't seem to work. I just tried CONFIG += no_keywords but it's a change for the worse I mean I get 114 errors.

Comment: true that works, but I have QObject's classes in my project and seems its causing problems.
Add to the example some empty class with base class e.g. QOject
http://paste.kde.org/p9qrwvve0

When I try to build I get 36 error. Any suggestion how to fix this ?

Comment: @krusty: that is _not_ an empty class. Change signals to Q_SIGNALS and slots to Q_SLOTS. See the last paragraph of the answer, i.e. the quoted documentation.

Comment: thank you, now I get it. Sorry sometimes I need to 'digest' new stuff.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, it helps immensely! As a side note, if you don't have a qmake project because you're using visual studio, you can just define `QT_NO_KEYWORDS` for the same effect.

Comment: Is this the only way around this problem? I'm faced with embedding Python in a huge existing Qt/C++ application. With this solution, that's a lot of searching/replacing throughout the code, and a lot of people who have to change their habits. Is there any other way to resolve/avoid the 'slots' conflict?

Comment: I found a solution; I'll post it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 28):

Another way to avoid the conflict regarding 'slots', without the need for deactivating the keywords signals/slots/emit (which may be undesirable for large Qt projects), is [to locally "park" the offending keyword while Python.h is included, and then reassign it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793800/can-i-redefine-a-c-macro-then-define-it-back). To achieve this, replace every occurrence of `#include "Python.h"` by the following block:

```
#pragma push_macro("slots")
#undef slots
#include "Python.h"
#pragma pop_macro("slots")
```

Or, more conveniently, put the above code in its own header, e.g. `Python_wrapper.h`, and replace all occurrences of `#include "Python.h"` by `#include "Python_wrapper.h"`.

Comment: That's perfect, compiles with msvc & clang on macOS at least. Definitely the correct answer!

Comment: It works on my ubuntu 20.04 Qt project, Better answer than the accepted one.

Comment: This fixed the syntax error but now it's giving me `Undefined symbols _Py_DecodeLocale`.  The application runs fine when I comment it out but it runs wrong version of python.. any ideas on how to fix this?