# Turning the no_keyword (Qt option) ON in a cmake file to work with boost::signals

Tags: qt, boost

I'm having problems using **Qt4** and **boost::signals**.

Searching the internet I found about the **no_keyword** options to put in a **.pro file**.

```
CONFIG += no_keywords
```

Problem is, the project I'm involved uses **cmake** and not **.pro** files.
So how do I turn this options on in a cmake file ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to add `ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DQT_NO_KEYWORDS)` to your CMakeLists.txt